# Ruby: enumerator can't be coerced to Fixnum; struggling with Project Euler #5

Tags: ruby, fixnum

The challenge is to find the smallest integer `foo` for which:

```
foo % 1..20 == 0
```

My current attempt is brute force

```
until foo % 1.upto(20) == 0 do
    foo++
end
```

This outputs the error `unexpected keyword end`. But if I don't put the `end` keyword into irb the code never runs, because the block isn't closed.

I made an empty test case to see where my error lays

```
until foo % 1.upto(20) == 0 do
end
```

This throws a new error: `enumerator can't be coerced to a fixnum`. I imagine this means you can't directly perform modulus upon a range and expect a neat boolean result for the whole range. But I don't know where to go from here.

My first attempts forewent brute force in favor of an attempt at something more efficient/elegant/to-the-point and were as follows:

```
foo = 1
1.upto(20) {|bar| foo *= bar unless foo % i == 0}
```

gave the wrong answer.  I don't understand why, but I'm also interested in why

```
foo = 1
20.downto(1) {|bar| foo *= bar unless foo % i == 0}
```

outputs a different answer.

**EDIT:** I would have used for loops (I got my feet wet with programming in ActionScript) but they do not work how I expect in ruby.

Comment: foo++ does not work as you might expect in Ruby. You need to write foo += 1

Comment: @David: That's my least favorite language feature...

Comment: @sarnold Least favorite in that you wish it was in Ruby, or you don't like it in other languages? It doesn't really make sense in Ruby (or OO in general perhaps) since numbers aren't mutable and `++` would thus involve a hidden assignment.

Comment: @Andrew: Don't try to placate me with _reasoning_ :) -- I just got very used to `foo++` in every language I use -- and then Ruby bites me.

Comment: @sarnold No I understand, I was used to it as well and was shocked when I started with Ruby. But seeing as `for` loops don't exist in Ruby as they do in those languages, I don't miss `++` too much.

Comment: I'm still very new to coding, currently trying to learn java while fiddling with ruby.  Through irb, it's my language of choice for these excersizes.  That said, I am already in love with upto() and downto() as well as the way ruby handles 'for each', so I don't feel tied down.  @OzBandit thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were me, I'd define a function to test the condition:

```
def mod_test(num)
  test = (1..20).map {|i| num % i == 0}
  test.all? # all are true
end
```

and then a loop to try different values:

```
foo = 20
until mod_test(foo) do
  foo += 20
end
```

(Thanks to [Dylan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645993/ruby-enumerator-cant-be-coerced-to-fixnum-struggling-with-project-euler-5#comment13803436_10646022) for the `+= 20` speedup.)

I'm sure that there's a clever way to use the knowledge of `foo % 10 == 0` to also imply that `foo % 5 == 0` and `foo % 2 == 0`, and perform only tests on prime numbers between `1` and `20`, and probably even use that information to construct the number directly -- but my code ran quickly enough.

Comment: You can actually just test 11..20 instead. If 20 works, so will 10; if 18 works, so will 9; etc.

Comment: @Dylan: An excellent point that will nearly cut the runtime in half. (Function calls will prevent it from being exactly half.) Nice. :)

Comment: @Dylan you have intriguing optimizations.  I have my work cut out understanding everyone's input.

Answer (score 3):

Your first solution is wrong because `1.upto(20)` is an *enumerator*, that is, essentially an iterator over the values 1 to 20, and it cannot be used as a number for modulo or comparison to another number, since it itself isn't a number.

You really need two "loops" here:

```
foo = 1
foo += 1 until (1..20).all? { |i| foo % i == 0 }
```

the first loop is the `until`, and then the [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) is another loop of sorts, in that it ensures that the block (`{ |i| foo % i == 0 }`) is true for each element in the range it is called on (`(1..20)`). Note that I'm using the one-line "backwards" syntax (which also works for `if`, `unless`, `while`, …)—the above is equivalent to:

```
foo = 1
until (1..20).all? { |i| foo % i == 0 } do
  foo += 1
end
# foo => 232792560
```

Also, this is incredibly inefficient, Project Euler often involves a bit more math than programming, and a non-brute-force solution will likely involve more math but be far faster.

Comment: As much I want to make the solutions to these problems "elegant", as of now I can only manage "messy".  I came up with an idea for a different approach after posting the question and I'm attempting to beat some code fragments into shape.  It's at least a step above brute force and I THINK it will work, but I need all the help I can get understanding where I got things wrong.  The fun part is how much this hurts my head after spending hours on it, increasing my basic competency.  The enlightening part is reading other people's (better) solutions afterward.  Thank you for the help on this end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
until 1.upto(20).reject{|i| foo % i == 0 }.empty? do
  foo += 1
end
```

Comment: Since it has to be divisible by 20, you can just start with `foo = 20` and add 20 each time instead of 1

Comment: Good idea, since I gave up around `foo=17740946`. :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to improve on the answer for purposes of solving the ProjectEuler problem - I was just providing a correct syntax for the attempted solution

Comment: So the reject method skips iteration over values satisfying that condition and empty ends iteration when the maximum value is reached?
Since 20 can be factored, are you really finding the lowest common multiple? I'm attempting a better solution than brute force, but it will rely on first eliminating common factors between the iterated values, except the value which has the most copies of the factor in question.  From there, multiply.

I'll at least attempt this solution.  Good practice even if it turns out wrong and overly complex but possibly at least more efficient than brute force.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not directly the OP question, but this is way easier to achieve with just:

```
puts (1..20).reduce(:lcm)
```

It's so simple that it seems like isn't fair to solve it this way, but that's precisely why Ruby is my language of choice for Project Euler.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783538/getting-the-least-common-multiple-of-an-array-of-integers-in-ruby)