# Getting the least common multiple of an array of integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know that, in Ruby, you can use the [`Integer#lcm`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-lcm) method to get the least common multiple of two numbers. For example:

```
10.lcm(15)
# => 30
```

Is there an efficient (or built-in to the core or stdlib) way to get the least common multiple of all the integers in a given array? For example:

```
[5, 3, 10, 2, 20].lcm
# => 60
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Any operation that takes two operands can be applied iteratively to a collection by [folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) it: [Enumerable#inject/reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). To cover the empty case, pass as first argument the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element#Examples) of the operation, which is `1` for the least common denominator.

```
[5, 3, 10, 2, 20].reduce(1) { |acc, n| acc.lcm(n) } # => 60
```

Which can be also written as:

```
[5, 3, 10, 2, 20].reduce(1, :lcm)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I only think of using reduce for basic arithmetic; I need to remember it in more complex situations!

Comment: what if I want to calculate It using logic other than **reduce** or **inject**

Comment: @JacksonJegatheesan, Instead of providing a method symbol to `#reduce`, you can also supply a block in which you can do the logic yourself. `[5,3,10,2,20].reduce(1) { |memo, element| memo.lcm(element) }` is identical. You can then also do other stuff in the block, like the non-sensical `[5,3,10,2,20].reduce(1) { |memo, element| memo = rand(memo) + element }`. The `memo` acts as the value that's being passed from block call to next block call.

Comment: @JochemSchulenklopper: Good point for a programmer new to Ruby, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tokland's answer, if you really want an `#lcm` method to act on an *array of integers*, you could add an instance method to the Array class.

```ruby
class Array
  def lcm
    self.reduce(1, :lcm)
  end
end

puts 10.lcm(15)
# => 30
puts [5,3,10,2,20].lcm
# => 60
```

(This practice is called [Monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), as you're extending a class at runtime. Some people do frown upon the practice though.)

Comment: Hello from Advent of Code 2020? :-)

Comment: Yes :-D I was looking up LCM discussions, and added this answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[5,3,10,2,20].reduce(&:lcm)
```